# PCB Connector for Sensitive ADC Component

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am evaluating [this expensive BGA ADC component](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ddc316.pdf), which has 16 analog inputs, by placing it on a custom dev board.

The analog input signals to this <strike>chip</strike> **dev board** will be 20 MHz current-based signals in the 100pA to 1uA RMS range. These signals originate from an arrayed APD detector which is being kept separate during development.

What type of board-to-board connector should be used to apply these currents to the ADC while maintaining signal integrity. Presumably I need a very short connector with extremely low parasitic capacitance, and probably EMI shielding.

The ADC's integrating capacitor is around 3pF, so I think the parasitic capacitance must be significantly less.

Comment: The integration rate of the ADC is 10uS minimum ie 100KHz - surely this is way too slow to sample your 20MHz signals?

Comment: There is more going on with the dev board than just direct connection of the signals. Various triggering, etc.

Comment: I totally agree with @Icy - this won't work as you expect.

Comment: Fifth line in the 'Features' on the first page of the datasheet: ```Data Rate Up To 100kSPS```. What makes you think you can meaningfully sample a 20MHz signal with a 100kSPS ADC?

Comment: I am not expecting to sample at 20 MHz using that component. There is other circuitry on the dev board which need the signal at full bandwidth. The question is about the connector, not the IC.

Answer (score 4):

There are a huge amount of choices for this I would think.  Maybe a [Qstrip](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/high-speed-board-to-board/mezzanine) similar to a mictor connector
[image]

It has a nice ground/reference plane in the middle and you can space the signals out from one another by using a connector with more pins than you need.  Maybe isolate around them with some GNDs and you should be okay.

Or I just used something like this, it's a high [isolation RF connector](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/high-speed-board-to-board/high-isolation-rf/isorate)
[image]